# JML Evaluation of \old(Expression[Id])

Tags: java, static-analysis, formal-verification, jml

I would like to know how a JML expression of the form `\old(Expression[Id])` is evaluated, i.e. if I have the `\old(vector[value-1])` expression, does the `\old` also refer to "value" or just the to the value of the `vector[value-1]`. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well hopefully you found the answer to your question elsewhere, but it's the first one:

`\old(vector[value-1])` is the value in the old vector at `\old(value)-1`.